# Passing a drop down value to Index ActionResult argument to refresh my view data

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I am new to C#, MVC, and JavaScript. Please pardon my ignorance.

I want to pass a selected drop down value, from my view to the controller, so that I can filter/refresh the grid in my view. I am able to get the value, using JavaScript. But I can't seem to get it to pass.

```
@Html.DropDownList("HubVal", new List<SelectListItem>
          { new SelectListItem { Text = "--SELECT--", Value = "" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 1", Value = "Option 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 2", Value = "Option 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 3", Value = "Option 3" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 4", Value = "Option 4" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 4", Value = "Option 4" }},
            new { id = "HubVal", style = " width: 100%; " })
```

my JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#HubVal').change(function () {
        var hubVal = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({        
            url: '@Url.Action("Index")' + hubVal,
            type: "POST",
            data: { hubValue: hubVal },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Your data has been saved")
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("FAILED");
            }

        })
    });
});
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string hubVal)
```

{

```
List<InventoryModel> inventoryModel = new List<InventoryModel>();
InventoryEntities inventoryDatabase = new InventoryEntities();

var customerQuery = (from myInventory in inventoryDatabase.table
                     where hubVal == myInventory.HubName
                     select new
                     {
                         hubMane = myInventory.HubName,
                         prop2 = myInventory.Prop2,
                         prop3 = myInventory.Prop3,
                         prop4 = myInventory.Prop4,
                         prop5 = myInventory.Prop5,
                         prop6 = myInventory.Prop6,
                         prop7 = myInventory.Prop7,
                         prop8 = myInventory.Prop8,
                         prop9 = myInventory.Prop9,
                         prop10 = myInventory.Prop10
                     }).ToList();


foreach (var item in customerQuery)
{
    InventoryModel oneItem = new InventoryModel
    {
        HubName = item.mx,
        prop2 = item.prop2,
        prop3 = item.prop3,
        prop4 = item.prop4,
        prop5 = item.prop5,
        prop6 = item.prop6,
        prop7 = item.prop7,
        prop8 = item.prop8,
        prop9 = item.prop9,
        prop10 = item.prop10
    };
    inventoryModel.Add(oneItem);
}

return View(inventoryModel);
```

}

Comment: Please look into the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) sections from the Help Centre. If my answer solved your original issue then please mark it as an accepted answer and ask any follow up questions separately. Also you can edit your question to update with any relevant information, hence you don't need to add answers to add more info to this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Ajax call fails to find the proper entry in your controller.
Try specifying the parameter name within the url like:

```
$.ajax({        
        url: '@Url.Action("Index")' + '?hubVal=' + hubVal,
        …
})
```

---

You can verify your Ajax call through the browser developer tool. Look for network tab and see what is actually posted by your code. Also there are tools that helps with REST calls so that you can test them separately from the View (like Postman or any other alternative).